# delphi какие базы данных можно использовать для хранения большого кол-ва настроек программы

Tags: delphi, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите где смотреть примеры и возможности разных баз.

Мои хотелки:

- Поддержка основных типов

  - списки
  - строки
  - числа
  - структуры
- Легкий доступ к полям и сложным структурам.
- Хранение списков в структуре без доп. таблиц.
- Хранение в одном файле.
- Простое добавление новый полей
- Многопоточность

Пару примеров желаймого доступа к бд

```
Bd['NewField'].Value:= 222;
Bd['ListName'][i]['Name']:= 'Кто-то';
Bd['Struct']['Date']:= Now;
```

Comment: Смотреть примеры и возможности лучше на официальных сайтах самих БД + поиск в нете. То что вы показали, это не совсем доступ к БД. Ну и так же не понятно, куда вы собираетесь эту БД ставить, какие объемы планируете там хранить и обрабатывать

Comment: Казалось бы, обычный json обернутый в крит.секцию все это вам даст.

Comment: А точно именно база данных нужна? Обычный json/yaml/toml не подходит? "Большое" количество - это сколько значений?

Comment: @insolor  
 Так у меня сейчас в json хранится. Мне сказали что json гомно. и нужна бд. я и сам хочу понять есть ли такая бд c возможностями json

Comment: @Kromster Хотелось бы иметь возможности Json но что бы данные не были полностью загружены в оперативку. Что вы говорите про json мне нравится. Но я уже с ним это все делаю. А вопрос задаю что бы найти альтернативу типо mb sql postgres

Comment: @SwaD
 бд должна быть в папке с exe данные не гигабайты +- 10-50мб там просто разные поля списки и структуры. если что-то великое то оно в отдельном файле будет  и это не нужно рассматривать в вопросе.

Comment: @vegat4 смотря для каких целей. Для конфига json слишком машинно-ориентирован, на мой вкус, toml подходит лучше. Ну и очень легко его сломать при ручном редактировании. Базы данных стоит брать разве что если не предполагается ручное редактирование конфига. В простейшем случае - берите sqlite (он как раз в виде файла базу хранит), json значения храните в колонках в текстовом виде, при загрузке парсите. "Большую" базу данных стоит брать разве что если у вас настройки где-то на сервере будут храниться.

Comment: Лезть в 10-50мб файл и руками что-то править - мало кто рискнет. Так что человекочитаемость наверное отметаем ))

Comment: @Kromster на человекочитаемость вообще побоку. Важна скорость надежность и все такое. Программа сама все редактирует и предоставит интерфейсы для редактирования

Comment: Конкурентный доступ к настройкам ожидается из многих потоков одного приложения или из многих одновременно-работающих приложений?

Comment: SQLite + JSON (XSuperObject, например) ИМХО. SQLite обеспечит удобное хранение и поиск объектов, а SO - как раз такой формат обращения, какой вам нужен.  Правда для поиска по каким-то полям их придётся хранить (или дублировать) отдельно в таблице. Ну или текстовый поиск использовать, то не лучший вариант. Самый извращённый вариант: корневые свойства хранить в отдельных полях, а дочерние списки и объекты - в JSON в соответствующих полях.

Comment: @Kromster ожидается только с одного exe. но для 2го варианта могу мютекс на файл кинуть есть в бд нет такой поддержки

Comment: Тогда по прежнему остаюсь на варианте "json". Разве что, чтобы не грузить его весь в память - побейте на фрагменты по секциям и выгружайте их после обращения. *"json гомно. и нужна бд"* это блаж - тогда уж на блокчейн переходить надо ))) Вспоминайте принципы проектирования - если у класса (сервиса) настроек есть четкий интерфейс и требования по скорости и памяти, то "пользователям" должно глубоко фиолетово, где и как хранятся настройки.